# Remove second nested element in nested tuple in Python

Tags: python-3.x

I have a list of tuples with coordinates:

```
((3.5, -0.5), (3.5, 0.5))
((3.5, 0.5), (4.5, 0.5))
((4.5, 0.5), (4.5, 1.5))
((4.5, 1.5), (5.5, 1.5))
((5.5, -0.5), (5.5, 0.5))
((5.5, 1.5), (5.5, 0.5))
```

Is there a way I can remove duplicated second elements and join first ones together? For example in the above example the following coordinates have duplicates:

```
((5.5, -0.5), (5.5, 0.5))
((5.5, 1.5), (5.5, 0.5))
```

I would like to remove (5.5, 0.5) and just keep the coordinate as following:

```
((5.5, -0.5), (5.5, 1.5))
```

I have tried the following code but I think something is missing since it does not work in this case:

```
removed = [t for t in (set(tuple(i) for i in coordinates))]
```

Comment: In tuple(i), you are storing one point (x,y). Then you are storing this point in set. So you are storing point(x,y) ... not x or y. Try different approach. Use dataframe in  pandas. Or there are different ways to achieve this. I think you are new to programming. Try it again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a `dict` with `keys` the second elements and `list`s of the first elements as `values`.

```py
>>> import pprint
>>> pprint.pprint(l)  # just pretty print you initial list 
[((3.5, -0.5), (3.5, 0.5)),
 ((3.5, 0.5), (4.5, 0.5)),
 ((4.5, 0.5), (4.5, 1.5)),
 ((4.5, 1.5), (5.5, 1.5)),
 ((5.5, -0.5), (5.5, 0.5)),
 ((5.5, 1.5), (5.5, 0.5))]
>>>
>>> d = {}
>>> for a, b in l:
...     if b in d:
...          d[b].append(a)
...     else:
...          d[b] = [a]
...
```

You can then use the `dict` to produce the desired result:

```py
>>> result = []
>>> for k, v in d.items():
...     if len(v) == 1:
...         result.append((v[0], k))
...     else:
...         result.append(tuple(v))
... 
>>> pprint.pprint(result)
[((3.5, -0.5), (3.5, 0.5)),
 ((3.5, 0.5), (4.5, 0.5)),
 ((4.5, 0.5), (4.5, 1.5)),
 ((4.5, 1.5), (5.5, 1.5)),
 ((5.5, -0.5), (5.5, 1.5))]
```